How to use app.y.gy to shorten a link without requiring an account
Navigate to https://app.y.gy/docs and scroll down the page and notice what it says:

Alternatively, y.gy allows URL shortening and QR code generation directly from the landing page without requiring sign-in or account creation.

Then navigate to https://app.y.gy/
Do not sign in.
I see a input field for the long URL but it is for the QR code generator:

What am I missing? Something obvious, I suppose, but I do not see any field for typing in or pasting in the long URL for link shortening.

Looks like based on the documentation. The option to create a short url requires you to log into an account. If in doubt contact support.

downvote ... asking about the use of web pages is off topic here

It is documented as not requiring a signin. I clearly quoted from the documentation page in my original post. I was asking because I couldn't understand why their documentation doesn't match the behavior.

https://superuser.com/help/on-topic  indicates you are correct about asking about websites being off topic. I will make a note of that for next time and for other sites on stack exchange.

If you read the rest of the stuff under the QR code generator, it is pretty obvious that you have to pay.
If you click on the pricing menu, you can see that you have to pay.
A short URL will have to be a URL on their domain.  Why would they give it to you for free?
Documentation can often be misleading and wrong.  That's life.
